# The BrowserKit component is not available

Tags: phpunit, symfony4, functional-testing

I've got an error when i try to launch my functional tests.
"The BrowserKit component is not available."

```
php ./bin/phpunit
#!/usr/bin/env php
PHPUnit 6.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing Project Test Suite
E..                                                                 3 / 3 (100%)

Time: 367 ms, Memory: 16.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) App\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testLoginPage
LogicException: You cannot create the client used in functional tests if the BrowserKit component is not available. Try running "composer require symfony/browser-kit".

xxx\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Test\WebTestCase.php:39
xxx\tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest.php:13

ERRORS!
Tests: 3, Assertions: 6, Errors: 1.
```

As you can see my unit tests are ok. 
But not my functionals and when I check my composer.json I can see it.

```
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/browser-kit": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/css-selector": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "4.2.*",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
    "symfony/test-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.2.*"
},
```

And it's present in my /vendor folder.

And there is my phpunit.xml.dist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
 backupStaticAttributes="false"
 bootstrap="config/bootstrap.php"
 cacheTokens="false"
 colors="true"
 convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
 convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
 convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
 forceCoversAnnotation="false"
 mapTestClassNameToCoveredClassName="false"

 processIsolation="false"
 stopOnError="false"
 stopOnFailure="false"
 stopOnIncomplete="false"
 stopOnSkipped="false"

 strict="false"
 verbose="false"
>

<php>
    <!-- The application kernel -->
    <env name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="App\Kernel" />

    <!-- ###+ symfony/framework-bundle ### -->
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="dev"/>
    <env name="APP_SECRET" value="xxxx"/>
    <!-- ###- symfony/framework-bundle ### -->

    <!-- ###+ nelmio/cors-bundle ### -->
    <env name="CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN" value="^https?://localhost(:[0-9]+)?$"/>
    <!-- ###- nelmio/cors-bundle ### -->

</php>

<loggin>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="./build/coverage" lowUpperBound="35"
   highLowerBound="70"/>/>
</loggin>

 <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
        <directory>./tests/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>

<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory>./src/</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

For finish this is my test

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class DefaultControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private $client = null;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->client = static::createClient();
    }

    public function testLoginPage()
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('index');
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', $url);

        $this->assertSame(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
        //$this->assertContains('Login', $crawler->filter('h1')->text());
    }
}
```

Have you got any ideas ?
Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Founded !
I think it was a problem with my composer.json

I uninstall both test-pack en phpunit-bridge and reinstall only test-pack.

```
composer remove --dev test-pack symfony/phpunit-bridge
composer require --dev test-pack
```

Answer (score 1):

As it was written in the error, you have to install the [BrowserKit](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/browser_kit.html) component:

```
composer require --dev symfony/browser-kit
```

Remove `--dev` if you need BrowserKit not only during tests.