# BrowserKit component is not available

Tags: php, symfony, testing, composer-php

I have a test that extends WebTestCase. It doesn't do much yet:

```
namespace Tests\Application\EndToEnd;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class AuthenticationTest extends WebTestCase

    {
        public function testAuthenticationMethodNotAllowed()
        {   
            $client = static::createClient();
            self::assertTrue(true);
        }
    }
```

But even this little bit is enough to trigger an error when I run the test:

There was 1 error:

> 1)
>   Tests\Application\EndToEnd\AuthenticationTest::testAuthenticationMethodNotAllowed
>   LogicException: You cannot create the client used in functional tests
>   if the BrowserKit component is not available. Try running "composer
>   require symfony/browser-kit".

Running `composer require symfony/browser-kit` and also `composer require --dev symfony/browser-kit` does not fix the problem.

I also tried the fix mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54871568/8252915), with no improvement.

Is this a known issue? Are there other approaches I should try?

===

Update: Here is the content in my `test.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <parameters>
        <parameter key="test.client.parameters" type="collection"></parameter>
    </parameters>

    <services>
        <defaults public="false" />

        <service id="test.client" class="Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client" shared="false" public="true">
            <argument type="service" id="kernel" />
            <argument>%test.client.parameters%</argument>
            <argument type="service" id="test.client.history" />
            <argument type="service" id="test.client.cookiejar" />
        </service>

        <service id="test.client.history" class="Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\History" shared="false" />

        <service id="test.client.cookiejar" class="Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\CookieJar" shared="false" />

        <service id="test.session.listener" class="Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TestSessionListener">
            <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" />
            <argument type="service_locator">
                <argument key="session" type="service" id="session" on-invalid="ignore" />
            </argument>
        </service>

        <service id="test.service_container" class="Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\TestContainer" public="true">
            <argument type="service" id="kernel" />
            <argument>test.private_services_locator</argument>
        </service>

        <service id="test.private_services_locator" class="Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ServiceLocator" public="true">
            <argument type="collection" />
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message is not only triggered when the BrowserKit component is not installed, but also when the `framework.test` config option is not `true` (as in this case the `test.client` service will never be registered).

You need to make sure that this option is enabled and that your test is actually executed in the `test` environment.

Comment: Thanks. Where do I set that config option?

Comment: Are you using Symfony Flex? In this case, you should already have a `config/packages/test/framework.yaml` file where this option is set to `true`.